# Custom Data File Extensions in C++

Tags: c++

Can one create and open a file (new file) with a non standard extension like .xyz, .abc etc in c++?

```
ofstream x("file.xyz",ios::out|ios::app);
```

Will this file be created and if at all it gets created what is the format of data that this file can hold? That is, will it be binary, text-based or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File names are just that, names. Extensions can be whatever you want them to be, and the same with the contents. Having a single three-letter extension is just a left-over from the old DOS (or maybe earlier CP/M) days. Today they don't really matter on a normal PC, no matter the operating system. In fact, there are only so many three-letter combinations available, so the extension `xyz` has certainly been used before by other programs, possibly many times and then most likely with completely different (and incompatible) formats.

Comment: But as a caveat, you should try to avoid using extensions of well known programs (.pdf, .doc, .docx, etc.) to prevent confusion of the user or the OS trying to launch your program with a different application.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a simple `ostream` `c++` will not care about the extension of the file. It will be opened as a text file in append mode. However when you double click on the file from the operating system it may try to execute it or to do some other weird stuff so it is generally recommended not to use existing extensions with special meaning.